# Return type 'parent' in php trait methods

Tags: php, phpstorm, traits, type-hinting

What does happen if a *trait* method declares the return type *parent* or does use *parent* as a parameter type?

PhpStorm seems to indicate that *parent* used in a *trait* does actually refer to **the class implementing the *trait*** which seems strange as *static* already does exactly this - doesn't it? If it's true that traits declare everything exactly as if the code would have been written in the implementing class, **shouldn't *parent* refer to the actual parent of the implementing class**? Does it actually do this (and only the IDE has a misleading type hint)?

```php
trait MyTrait {
    public function doSomething(parent $parent): parent
    {
        return $parent
    }
}

class MyClass extends MyParentClass{
    use MyTrait;
    public function doSomethingElse() {
        $parent = new MyParentClass();
        $this->doSomething($parent);
    }
}
```

Is `$parent (MyParentClass)` a valid parameter for `$this->doSomethingElse` here? Or will this throw a type error, because the trait expects an instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: You wrote some code to test in PHP storms, but you forgot to include it in your question?

Comment: Well I just thought the question was clear enough - but I'll add some dummy code.

Comment: You can also access your parent through parent::nameMethod. https://masteringbackend.com/posts/self-static-and-parent-in-php

Comment: @Wimanicesir That's true but actually not my question.

Comment: You could do some experiments and see the result for all the PHP versions here: https://3v4l.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you use `parent` in a `trait` it referrs to the parent of the class which is using the trait - as expected.**

Testing it in a real world example (yes, I could have done this before...) showed, that everything works as expected: `MyTrait::doSomething` does expect `MyParentClass` as parameter and return value. So only the IDE hint (`MyClass`) is wrong.

Comment: This question, and answer, seems to revolve around your usage of PhpStorm, so I added that as a tag to your question.